# Why is this CSS property not detailed in the JavaFX CSS Reference Guide?

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'm learning how to use CSS to style UI components in JavaFX, and in going through Oracle's tutorials I found the color property `-fx-base` in a piece of example code:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/button.htm (example 3-5, the very last piece of code on the page).

In the complete JavaFX CSS Reference Guide (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html), there is clear documentation on every property I have seen so far EXCEPT `-fx-base`, and it seems that it isn't in the reference guide at all. Am I searching in the wrong place or is it missing? Are there any other undocumented properties?

Answer (score 4):

`-fx-base` is a [looked-up color](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typecolor) - not really a property - defined in the default [modena.css](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css) stylesheet.

Looked-up colors effectively work as color-valued variables which can be set on a node in the scene graph. They propagate to descendant nodes. The default stylesheet uses looked-up colors extensively. Almost (but not quite all) colors used in modena are defined in terms of `-fx-base`.

To my knowledge, there's currently no official documentation on which looked-up colors are defined and how they are used. You can, and I do fairly frequently, dig into the [modena.css](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css) source code to see how to use and manipulate these.

Comment: I see, so `-fx-base` is like a custom-defined property in the default sheet then. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's documented immediately below the example 3-5 code at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/button.htm:

"The -fx-font property sets the font name and size for button1. The **-fx-base property overrides the default color applied to the button**. As the result, button1 is light green with lager text size, as shown in Figure 3-5."

Comment: I did see that on the tutorial page, but I was looking for more detailed information along with the rest of the CSS documentation.