# In javafx how do i change the color of a button, wait 1 second than change it back do default?

Tags: java, button, javafx, fxml, background-color

So i want to change the color of a button to light green, wait 1 second than change it back to default.
How can i do this? I tried it this way:

```
button1.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightgreen");

try { Thread.sleep(1000); }

catch(InterruptedException e) {}

button1.setStyle("");
```

But i have 2 problems:

1. the color never sets to light green, only to default.
2. if i want to change it only to light green, it only changes after the 1 second of waiting and not before it.

Edit:

So i got to the part to use PauseTransition, but it won't work the way i want it to.

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
   int x = rand.nextInt(4) + 1;
            switch(x) {
                case 1: {
                    System.out.println("b1");
                    button1.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightgreen; -fx-border-color: black;");

                    PauseTransition wait = newPauseTransition(Duration.seconds(1));
                    wait.setOnFinished(event -> {
                    button1.setStyle("");
                });
                wait.play();
            }
            break;
            case 2: {
                System.out.println("b2");
                button2.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightgreen; -fx-border-color: black;");

                PauseTransition wait = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(1));
                wait.setOnFinished(event -> {
                    button2.setStyle("");
                });
                wait.play();
            }
            break;
            ...
}
```

Now the problem is that the while() won't wait until the button turns back to default, and it starts a new iteration.

Comment: Try [`-fx-base`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24877022/why-is-this-css-property-not-detailed-in-the-javafx-css-reference-guide) instead of `-fx-background-color`.  Look into `PauseTransition`.  Never use `Thread.sleep()` on the UI thread.

Comment: Im trying PauseTransition now, but the problem is that, the program won't wait for 1 sec, only the button will turn to light green for 1 sec. Because i want all this in a cycle, so i need the program to wait aswell.

Comment: What do you mean by "i need the program to wait"?  You may need to add more code ([mcve]) to explain that.  Or perhaps ask a new question as the color change and pause would seem to be answered using a PauseTransiton.

Comment: i have a while(i<3), every iteration i get a random number(1 2 3 or 4) which will make button1,2,3or4 change to light green and back to default. But for some reason all the buttons that need to change color, become lightgreen at once and reset to default at one. When i need them to change color and back in the order of the incoming random numbers.

Comment: Don't code while loops on the UI thread for time based logic and put sleep calls there.  It won't work, you need to release the UI thread, so that it can paint the UI.  JavaFX has facilities for that (timelines, transitions and animation timers). I think your original question is answered.  Ask new questions with a [mcve].

Comment: I have used pseudo-class change, it worked better to dynamicly change a pseudo-class than a style see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37072514/how-to-add-class-or-pseudoclass-programmatically-to-custom-control-in-javafx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to change the color of a random button, wait 1 sec then change it back to default, int a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59732441/i-want-to-change-the-color-of-a-random-button-wait-1-sec-then-change-it-back-to)

Answer (score 4):

1. Use `-fx-base` instead of `-fx-background-color`.
2. Use `PauseTransition`.
3. Never use `Thread.sleep()` on the UI thread.

Sample code:

```
button.setStyle("-fx-base: lightgreen");
PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(
    Duration.seconds(1),
);
pause.setOnFinished(event -> {
    button.setStyle(null);
});
pause.play();
```