# I want to change the color of a random button, wait 1 sec then change it back to default, int a for loop

Tags: java, button, javafx, background-color, scenebuilder

i want to make a code where with every iteration i get a random number, and based on that number a button changes its color to lightgreen then after one second it changes back to default, but my problem is that the for() won't wait until the button changes back, and it starts it's new iteration.
This is my code so far:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
     int x = rand.nextInt(4) + 1;
        switch(x) {
            case 1: {
                System.out.println("b1");
                button1.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightgreen; -fx-border-color: black;");

                PauseTransition wait = newPauseTransition(Duration.seconds(1));
                wait.setOnFinished(event -> {
                button1.setStyle("");
            });
            wait.play();
        }
        break;
        case 2: {
            System.out.println("b2");
            button2.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightgreen; -fx-border-color: black;");

            PauseTransition wait = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(1));
            wait.setOnFinished(event -> {
                button2.setStyle("");
            });
            wait.play();
        }
        break;
        ...
}
```

How can i make this work so that the loop won't block the UI updates? I saw something about maming a new Thread for the loop but i can't seem to figure aout how to do it, and where to use the Platform.runLater.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following code does what you want.  It uses a Timeline to choose a button at random, every second, and set the button to a green color, while any button which had its color previously set is reset to the default color.

[image: snapshot]

```
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.util.Random;

public class RandomLighting extends Application {
    private static final int NUM_BUTTONS = 4;
    private static final Duration LIGHT_DURATION = Duration.seconds(1);
    private static final HBox buttons = new HBox(10);

    private static final String LIT_STYLE = "-fx-base: lightgreen;";
    private static Random random;

    private Button litButton;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        random = new Random(42);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        buttons.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_BUTTONS; i++) {
            buttons.getChildren().add(new Button("" + (i + 1)));
        }

        Timeline lightAnimation = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, 
                        event -> lightButton(chooseRandomButton())
                ),
                new KeyFrame(LIGHT_DURATION)
        );
        lightAnimation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(buttons));
        stage.show();

        lightAnimation.play();
    }

    private Button chooseRandomButton() {
        ObservableList<Node> candidates = buttons.getChildren();
        return (Button) candidates.get(random.nextInt(candidates.size()));
    }

    private void lightButton(Button button) {
        if (litButton == button) {
            return;
        }

        if (litButton != null) {
            litButton.setStyle(null);
        }

        litButton = button;

        if (litButton != null) {
            button.setStyle(LIT_STYLE);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```